# Can you make Arduino Uno send information through a WiFi module to a server?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, web-server

A lot of tutorials are about how to control Arduino through WiFi, but I need my Arduino to send information about motion sensor activity to a server. Is that possible?

Comment: The key words to search are "web request" together with arduino. I think there is a client library, that you can use. Depending on your used hardware

Comment: What do you want the server to do with your sensor activity? Have you looked into things like IoT (“internet of things”)?

Answer (score 2):

> Can you make Arduino Uno send information through a WiFi module to a server?

Yes, I can.

The simplest way is through an HTTP "GET" request. Every time you request a web page (and there are plenty of examples of that) you are sending data to the server to tell it both what web page to get (`/foo/bar.php`) and what data to submit to that web page (`?baz=4`).

It's then up to you to craft that GET request, such as:

```
GET /foo/bar.php?baz=4 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-length: 0
```

and write the PHP web page (or whatever language you prefer to write web pages in) to do something meaningful with the "baz = 4" parameter.